# What happens to the soul if a womb is aborted?

Tags: atma, rebirth

What happens to a soul if the womb is aborted?  Does the soul take another birth or it attains salvation?

Comment: why will it attain salvation ?? dying in womb is no different from normal death - if your karmas are over then you get moksha, if not you have more birth.